# How to avoid duplicates in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm using a relational database which contains two tables:

```
PASSWORD:
  id (primary key)
  idEquipment (Foreign key)
  password (varchar)

EQUIPMENT :
  id (primary key and REFERENCES)
  type (varchar)
  model (varchar)
```

The question is how to avoid duplicates password in the table `PASSWORD` because many equipments have the same value of password ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: unique! But why disallow duplicates - is that really integrity safe?

Comment: Please don’t store passwords in plain text. Also, what does it matter two passwords are the same? I don’t know your use case but it’s perfectly find for two users to have the same password in a system, as there’s usually some other piece of information to identify them (i.e. username or email address).

Comment: This use case looks to be storing passwords for equipment they manage, ie a password manager.  So storing it plaintext isn't the end of the world as long as they secure access to the db - I agree, it would be better with some encryption scheme, but not essential.  Your point about sharing two passwords also stands too.

Comment: @JoshWeatherly That’s not the point. People still use the same password across all online services. So if this database was compromised and passwords mapped to users, attackers could then start trying those same passwords for their social media accounts, online banking portals, webmail, and so on. It’s recommended passwords are hashed for a reason.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, now I understand too much better.

Answer (score 0):

[Unique](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) would be a solution for you

```
PASSWORD:
  id (primary key)
  idEquipment (Foreign key)
  password (varchar) UNIQUE

EQUIPMENT :
  id (primary key and REFERENCES)
  type (varchar)
  model (varchar)
```